# Why didn't Clara do what humans were supposed to do when encountering the Silent?

Tags: doctor-who, the-silence

Before meeting the Doctor, Clara (the un-impossible one, if you want) led a normal life. That most likely includes watching the Moon Landing. Which, as [*Day of the Moon*](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Day_of_the_Moon_%28TV_story%29) showed,

> included a recording of a Silent post-hypnotically ordering the viewer to "kill us [(the Silent)] all on sight".

In [*The Time of the Doctor*](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Time_of_the_Doctor_%28TV_story%29), Clara encounters Silents while visiting the Papal Mainframe. So, why doesn't the aforementioned **spoiler** kick in, i.e.

> why doesn't she try to kill them instead of fleeing in terror?

Comment: And in extension, why didn't Rory and Amy do so on every occasion? Of course, their lightning hands might have prevented them from doing so, but nonetheless they should have tried...

Comment: Huh, funny, [that one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4078/769) has actually already been asked... [Twice](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36597/why-dont-the-doctor-amy-rory-or-river-kill-the-silents-on-sight).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mainly because Clara was born **after** the events of *"Day of the moon"*.

Clara was born 23rd November, **1986**, whereas *Day of the moon* occurs in **1969**.

Relevant excerpt from *[Death in Heaven](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/34-12.html)*

> CYBERMAN: **Born 23rd November, 1986.**
>
> CLARA: Yeah, I chose that date. Always liked it.

This gives us a fair probability that she hasn't seen the footage. According to the comments below, (& Personal experience) this isn't very far-fetched.

The main punch of the footage was the world-wide broadcast in 1969, when a *huge* majority of people would be watching it.

Also another thing to remember, Clara doesn't really have anything to kill the Silent with. To the point that she *was* naked (kinda, not really, but very much yes.. It's all... wibbly wobbly) at that point.

Comment: They made a point that even a recording of the video would work so they didn't have to watch it live. Let me see if I can find the script

Comment: It's not about watching it live. The video would've started the biggest Silent genocide, and 23 years is a long time!

Comment: @cde - Doctor says that *"They won't even know they're doing it"*. Not that they wouldn't have to watch the video. Without the video, there would be no hypnotic suggestion to kill the Silent. The only way it would work was *with* the video. Otherwise the entire plot doesn't make any sense.

Comment: ***A bit of history for you. Aren't you proud? Because you helped. Now, do you know how many people are watching this live on the telly? Half a billion. And that's nothing, because the human race will spread out among the stars. You just watch them fly. Billions and billions of them, for billions and billions of years, and every single one of them at some point in their lives, will look back at this man, taking that very first step, and they will never, ever forget it.***

Comment: The point being is that it's unlikely Clara never watched a clip of the moon landing.

Comment: @cde - fair point. But we can't really count on that.

Comment: @cde Curiously enough, [this answer to the similar "why didn't _Amy_ kill them" question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/23564/769) suggests it isn't _that_ unlikely...

Comment: Well, I am American. Silly brits ignoring history.

Comment: @Zommuter - thanks! I had a feeling this wouldn't be so widespread...

Comment: @cde Got that backwards.  I'm in the US, not the UK.  Dunno about Stefan

Comment: @Izkata i meant the characters :P

Comment: It's not that ridiculous. I know people who have NEVER seen the moon landing recordings. We don't know if it required them to be seen in their entirety, we don't know if it required a complete audio soundtrack. I can see the Silent trying to create reasons for people to "lose" the soundtrack so the command could be lost as well. There could be any number of reasons, Clara didn't react to the Silent when she first saw them. You don't get to control the Human race for 200,000 years without a backup plan or two.

Comment: TBH the episode was the first time I had watched the moon landing footage...

Comment: @Stark07 So you should be affected :P

Comment: LOL... I do not remember a couple of minutes right after the episode though :O o.O -_- :P

Answer (score 1):

In The Wedding of River Song it was raised and the doctor said the time paradoxes had changed history. Also he fought alongside the silence on trenzalore. History is in flux in the whoverse.